# why the value is null after close modal

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have this link that pass BackTab value to controller

```js
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "View_All_SupportTickets"
  , new { BackTab = @ViewBag.CurrentSort })
```

it is working fine but when i open and close modal that found in the same  page i got null value of BackTab but before opening modal there was  a real value it looks like the page clear data after closing modal
i appreciate your assistance
thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if the changes after the modal is closed. You need to check in your code if that is happening. With the amount of code and description you have shared it's not possible to guess anything.

Comment: I resolved it thanks :)